# Trying to use Google Sheets to query a MySQL secured with an ssh key. How can the connection be established?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi my MySQL database is sitting behind an AWS EC2 machine with a SSH key tunnel.

How to I leverage Google App Script to query data from my database and pull it into my Google Sheet.

Anybody any insights?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is supported, given that the docs require you to have open access to the database server from [several IP address ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. A quick follow-up, would allowing open access to those IP Addresses bypass the SSH input? And if so, how can this be done on a EC2 instance? I'm a newbie so forgive the basic question.

Comment: I hesitate to answer authoritatively because I have only a passing familiarity with integrating Google Sheets with MySQL, but yes I believe the SS**H** tunnel must be eliminated and your server, or a proxy for it, must accept connections from the Internet, which is not really consistent with best practices.  Granted, it is fixed range, and you might be able to use SS**L**, but it's still something that would give your security officer nightmares.